# Why does URL return response from Postman but not Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, postman

I'm trying to pull data from this URL. It works in Postman but not locally in Python (3.8). The connection closes without a response. Also tried manually passing in my browser cookies but had the same results.

Below is the code generated from Postman after copying the XHR response as cURL (bash)

```
import requests

url = "https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Settlements/Futures/Settlements/10047/FUT?tradeDate=10/07/2022"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Cookie': 'ak_bmsc=40201F1BC4FD8456EED03A38A16CBC95~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQj2V0aGgBgqeDAQAAPzYKsxFH4BM3CXIxGLs0BpfFzUiVR7t+Ul6Q9U64ItnBxPPhosD8CEBZ03QGfv4XHioHnh1Hzn3E0Kc17EV4dAMLsUySAsUwh3Q+MD9zf5gNh4nCZXkoP+ChCHkYJ+uR1qxnPRZK8yu4USf8by8Js6LcoO3X2WPWkHw5LAsBcImL5hdhYDCX9n2bS3j/vHRyT2cg6iE0YLrAK6eLwgp6w8EFN9JhRKyL8AGYcYEJm6Rxk2EFQ62cG12uSW5pSl/h5yF/Z5qF8+0xXi3yhcBZ9vEvz9W8YPw9gbreYAvURg4wZtkxtxJyBkgfwlGkbc+NnzcErzlmH2b9ZYjs+vuP3GK0zP/c1e3BKgVEz/iQ; bm_sv=4E1D62DAE9E148686F96340796FD4A79~YAAQj2V0aDr/hKeDAQAAuChCsxGk32eAruqs2a29BNi48QW5E1rqQqbyowotXKQ1+hoMqvIsxi/uXHUQ+csp+U4/P6dMDker8yWYw80MxnzYfQ0k1UMD4VtKUGthUwGgBHrP42vpUbUMkVXVgjJh6OQrEwEFyP9T/wZGi8HraSMtkUJ2fmySYJtHS5Hvxr5oGlv9RtG2zlsq30gBxaJI1Y/j5HTh1hIKLsmI/VmrrTU9kI3M4zgoAF+TU8C1tWGG8bhr~1'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

EDIT: I had to modify the cURL as I was getting an error importing it into Postman. This is the cURL (bash) I used in Postman that returned the proper response:

```
curl 'https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Settlements/Futures/Settlements/10047/FUT?strategy=DEFAULT&tradeDate=10/07/2022&pageSize=500&isProtected&_t=1665158458937' \
```

Any ideas how to fix the request? None of the other SO threads seemed to have the answer.

Comment: You’re missing quite a few headers from the known-hood cURL request in your Python equivalent, no? Have you considered maybe the target server is checking one or more of those headers and generating the response accordingly?

Comment: For one, you only provide a cookie in your python implementation but you can see multiple header values in the curl implementation. I would try replicating those in your python implementation first.

Comment: You need to provide a User-Agent. In fact that's the only header you'll need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the User-Agent header and that's actually all you need for this URL

```
import requests

AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Safari/605.1.15'
URL = "https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Settlements/Futures/Settlements/10047/FUT?tradeDate=10/07/2022"
headers = {'User-Agent': AGENT}

(r := requests.get(URL, headers=headers)).raise_for_status()
print(r.json())
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Postman provides it's own User-Agent which is why the request was succesful on there but not locally. Thank you, OldBill!  For my own edification, how did you know you only need that one header?

Comment: @grahamrob When working with *requests* you should always provide a User-Agent. The website won't always require it but if it's there and not required it's benign. Also, as you started with Postman, you can see what headers were used by default

Comment: Damn, I definitely should have known that already. Thanks for the help.